# Invoking static function from process defined in library

Tags: c++

Trying to access static function defined in the  shared library class linked by process. static function to create instance so that the class is singleton.

Question:

can I not invoke static function in the process defined in library?

Example:
    library_file.h

```
 class api{

   public:

  static api* getinstance();

private:

    static api* mapi;

}api;

api::getinstance()
{
    if (mapi == 0)
    mapi =  new mapi();

     return mapi;
}
```

example process linked to the above library  fails:

```
#include "library_file.h"

int main()
{
   api *obj = api::getinstance();
}
```

**compilation error: undefined reference to api::getinstance()**

but this example process linked to the above library  works fine:

```
#include " library_file.h"

int main()
 {
    api obj;
 }


Edited:    
          Compiler output:
       D:/MyApplication/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7 -Wl,
       --no- keep-memory  -lang-c++ -lang-c++    -o

      D:/MyApplication/Api_Library/testapp/arm/o-le-v7/testapp    testapp.o   
        -L . -L 

        D:/MyApplication/Api_Library/testapp/target/qnx6/usr/lib -L 
        D:/MyApplication/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -L 
        D:/MyApplication/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib  -Wl,--rpath-link . -
         Wl,--rpath-link 

        D:/MyApplication/Api_Library/testapp/target/qnx6/usr/lib -Wl,--
        rpath-link 

        D:/MyApplication/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,--rpath-link 
        D:/MyApplication/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib    -Bdynamic    -
        lApi_Library   -EL          

        testapp.o: In function `main':

        testapp.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `api::getinstance()'
        cc: D:/MyApplication/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntoarm-ld caught signal 
          1

        make.exe[2]: *** [D:/MyApplication/Api_Library/testapp/arm/o-le-
          v7/testapp] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you linking against the library? Is the static function exported from the library?

Comment: cheers and hth - can you let me know what you meant?  when i compile library there is no error but when invoke from process it is failing.  so that means we cannot invoke static function from process?

Comment: @Proper: define "is failing".

Comment: Have you tried asking your compiler for more warnings? E.g. with Visual C++ use option `/W4`, with g++ use options `-Wall` `-Wextra`. With g++ also ask for standard-conformance via `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: I have added the compilation out put. I am using qnx momentics.

Comment: After properly linking the library the issue got resolved.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of `api::getinstance` does not match declations of `api::getinstance`.
You are missing the return type on the definiton of `api::getinstance`.

change it to:
**`api*`**`api::getinstance()`

And also remove `api` from the end of your class declaration.